# Append PHP code into jQuery.

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a jquery function include html select and input, it shows form with selectable value name is olcu

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        var fMiktar = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"miktar\" name=\"miktar[]\" size=\"6px\" />");
        var fOlcu = $("<select class=\"olcu\" name=\"olcu[]\"><option value=\"Adet\">Adet</option><option value=\"Metre\">Metre</option><option value=\"Gram\">Gram</option></select>");
        var fMalzeme = $("<input type=\"text\" name=\"malzeme[]\" class=\"malzeme\" id=\"aramayap\" />");
        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        fieldWrapper.append(fMiktar);
        fieldWrapper.append(fOlcu);
        fieldWrapper.append(fMalzeme);
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
    });

});
</script>
```

I want to take values of olcu from database

And here is the database code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showSelected(val){
        document.getElementById ('selectedResult').innerHTML = "" + val;
    }

</script>

<select name="olcu[]" onChange='showSelected(this.value)' class="olcu" id="olcu">Olcu Sec/option>

<?php

while($olculer=mysql_fetch_array($hangiolcu)){
echo "<option value='$olculer[olcu]'>$olculer[olcu]</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

How can I append or replace that sql code into this jquery line

```
var fOlcu = $("<select class=\"olcu\" name=\"olcu[]\"><option value=\"Adet\">Adet</option><option value=\"Metre\">Metre</option><option value=\"Gram\">Gram</option></select>");
```

Comment: Why don't you use better jQuery selector for elements? *by giving `class` name or `ID` ?*

Comment: this looks strange (mix od javascript and php code), why dont you get data with ajax?

Comment: AJAX is the way to go here.

Comment: Your *Database Code* is not database code. It simply prints options from your database query. What you actually want to achieve is very unclear. What is that jQuery line supposed to do? I think you might have a [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: can you please add combined code?

Answer (score 2):

You can create Javascript/jQuery variable with PHP code like this:

```
var foo = '<?php //echo or return php value here; ?>';
```

Comment: Can you please combine code?